# Adding normal fit, vertical lines and individual data points to diagonal on seaborn pairplot

Tags: seaborn, diagonal

[Output_Figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMbPt.png)

I am trying to add some extras to the diagonal of my sns.pairplot. Currently I'm using the kde option which is what I'd like to keep.  However, I would also like to overlay the following on each diagonal kde plot:

1. A normal distribution of the data
2. Vertical lines showing where 2,3,4 sigma would be
3. The location of the individual points along the diagonals, similar to the rug option in sns.displot.

So far, I've been able to add some vertical and horizontal lines to the non-diagonal plots, which I'm happy with, but I cannot seem to make anything plot for the diagonals.

Any help is much appreciated.

So far this is a snippet from my working code, using a standard seaborn dataset:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd    
import seaborn as sns


penguins = sns.load_dataset("penguins")

#########################################################################################################
## function that overlays the scatter plots in the pairs plot with the X% extension of max/min boxes.
PctExtension = 50  # how much percent extension do you want to draw the bounding box beyond the min and max?

def plot_pctBox(xdata, ydata, **kwargs):
    pct_xdata = [xdata.min() - ((xdata.max() - xdata.min())*(0.01*PctExtension)), xdata.max() + ((xdata.max() - xdata.min())*(0.01*PctExtension))]
    pct_ydata = [ydata.min() - ((ydata.max() - ydata.min())*(0.01*PctExtension)), ydata.max() + ((ydata.max() - ydata.min())*(0.01*PctExtension))]
    print('The bounding box range is: ' , pct_xdata)
    #print('The new max x is: ' , pct_xdata[1])
    plt.gca().axvline(x=pct_xdata[0], color='k', marker=None,
            linestyle='--', linewidth=1.0)
    plt.gca().axvline(x=pct_xdata[1], color='k', marker=None,
            linestyle='--', linewidth=1.0)
    plt.gca().axhline(y=pct_ydata[0], color='k', marker=None,
            linestyle='--', linewidth=1.0)
    plt.gca().axhline(y=pct_ydata[1], color='k', marker=None,
            linestyle='--', linewidth=1.0)   
###########################################################################################################    
            

grid = sns.pairplot(penguins, kind='scatter', diag_kind='kde',markers=None, height=2.5, aspect=1, diag_kws=None, grid_kws=None, size=None) # call the pairs plot.
grid.map_offdiag(plot_pctBox)  # call the % boxes.  
grid.fig.suptitle('50%ext bounding box/ Penguins', y=1)
```

Comment: Maybe someone could answer this as, but I certainly could not without any data. Are you able to share a subset of data or use a seaborn dataset with `sns.load_dataset`. You could also share images as well if you find a seaborn dataset that works for this problem or if you provide sample data.

Comment: Thanks, I have now updated the code to use a seaborn dataset, and there should also be a link to the figure generated with my output.  Apparently I'm not allowed to embed an image quite yet since I'm new here.

Comment: "I cannot seem to make anything plot for the diagonals." The function you're using is called `map_offdiag` because it plots on the off-diagonal axes. Have you tried using `map_diag` and not had success? It takes only one data argument, so you'll have to define a different function or adapt yours to handle only `xdata`.

Comment: Hi @mwaskom. I have tried the map_diag as well, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Ah yes, @mwaskom, I had tried the map_diag before, but neglected to realize that the function it uses can only handle xdata. Before, I had it requiring xdata and ydata.  Now using map_diag works.  Thanks!! Perhaps that is also your issue @user14771692?